# Using conditions in Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regex with some condition on it, (i.e),

(?(expression1)expression2)

In doing so, I need only expression2 to be returned and not expression1. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to return only `expression2` only when it is preceded by `expression1`

Then you want to do this:

```
(?<=expression1)expression2
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex supports conditionals in the form:

```
(?(?=regex)then|else)
```

If the lookahead succeeds, the "then" part must match for the overall regex to match. If the lookahead fails, the "else" part must match for the overall regex to match. Not just positive lookahead, but all four lookarounds can be used. Note that the lookahead is zero-width, so the "then" and "else" parts need to match and consume the part of the text matched by the lookahead as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Zero-width negative lookahead:

```
(?!expression1)(expression2)
```

this will negate the entire match if expression1 is matched.